# React: Update child with parent state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious here, but cannot seem to get this to work:

I have a parent component that calls two children.

PARENT

```
<PropertyCard model={property} onMouseOver={this.handlePropertyCardHover.bind(this, property)} />
<Map markers={places} options={mapOptions} activeRef={this.state.hoveredCard} />
```

When I hover over a PropertyCard a function is called to update the state `hoveredCard` within the parent.

PARENT

```
handlePropertyCardHover = (property) => {
    this.state.hoveredCard = property.id;
}
```

This part works and I can see the parent state being updated yet when it is passed down to the second child, `Map` nothing is updated.

MAP

```
<h1>{this.props.activeRef}</h1>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change your state, you have to use this.setState.

```
this.setState({hoveredCard : property.id})
```

instead of

```
this.state.hoveredCard = property.id;
```

Comment: Wow - that's embarrassing. Think I need a break from the screen :)